# Subscribe to an array of HTTP observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of `Observable` contained in `activatedRoute.data.example` and i want to subscribe to the latest value emitted.

```
private data$ = forkJoin(
  this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
    map(({ examples }) => examples)
  )
);

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
}
```

Every `example` here is an http request:

```
this.http.get<Example>(`${this.baseUrl}`, { params: query })
```

But I never see neither the `log` nor the API call to the backend in the network browser's tab.

Comment: ForkJoin will not work in your case, it is emitting values, when the all of the passed observables will be completed. just remove it and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question if you have time: there is a way to determine whether all observables has completed?

Comment: When you subscribe to an observable there are 3 param functions. `next`, `error`, `complete`. You know that an subscription is completed when the `complete` function is been called.

Comment: Be aware that HTTP client auto completes the subscription when the HTTP call finishes, that is not usually happens with the other observables (router events, store subscriptions, etc...)

Comment: @StPaulis this is the difference of hot and cold observables.

Answer (score 1):

*map* is an option, clearer way to do it with *switchMap* with *from* rxjs operators (you can also look for concatMap and mergeMap). So in the implementation, you can basically do:

```
  this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
    map(({ examples }) => from(examples)),
    concatMap((examples) => examples)
  ).subscribe(...);
```

If that was not helpful, I'm attaching a [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uo5ghe?file=src/app/app.component.ts) .

Comment: This is not really a realistic solution, it works in your stackBlitz because you are making use of `of()`, which is returning response there and then, but in real API has a travel delay, if you put a delay in your example, only the last response will ever get a response.

Comment: This is a mock solution. I don't think there'll be a difference in real world application. of() creates observable there, but it doesn't change code logic, we run our code logic on pipe(). It's independent of when observable is created. I rearranged the example for you. I added a mock delay, it still works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rv8bho?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: And also, at that moment he has the array of observables.

Comment: "Every example here is an http request", means example is an API Observable, you are placing the `delay` at the wrong place,  try this `[of(1).pipe(delay(1)), of(2)]` you will get  my point.

Comment: Yeah, you are right in that case switchMap returns immediately whenever one these observables complete. I thought he needed  this. But if not, using concatMap instead of switchMap will solve the issue. See the the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bdzwxh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Agreed, concatMap should solve his issue.

Comment: can you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

`map` of rxjs is not same as 'map' of Array.

Rough example of show it should actually work:

```
private data$: Observable;

ngOnInit(): void {

  let getExample = (query) => this.http.get < Example > (`${this.baseUrl}`, {
    params: query
  });

  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ examples}) => { // if example is array 

    let obsArray: Observable[] = Object.entries(examples).map(([key, value] => getExample({
        [key]: value
      }));
      
      data$ = forkJoin(obsArray); 
      data$.subscribe(); // if needed
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved returning directly the `forkJoin()` of the `Observable`s from the resolver, and than subscribing to that `Observable` throuhg a `ReplaySubject`